# Bug with a onload(), works only for testing alert

Tags: if-statement, url, iframe, alert, onload

I have a problem with my function `onload()`. I started onload at body

```
<body onload="myLoad();">
```

and I made a script

```
<script>
    function myLoad() {
        alert("Test");
    }
</script>
```

It worked for this version. But when I added more in script it stopped work.

```
<script>
    function myLoad() {
        alert("Test");
        var URL == window.location.pathname;
        if (URL == "index.html#offers")
            {
                document.getElementById("autoiframe").src = "Kontakt.html";
            }
        }
</script>
```

I don't understand why in second version alert stopped work (?). Ofcourse testing url also doesn't work. Where is a problem? What should I change? 
Thank you in advance. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think just replace `var URL == window.location.pathname;` to `var URL = window.location.pathname;`

Answer (score 0):

True, I had to change it and also .pathname for .href ^^

```
function myLoad() {
                    var URL = window.location.href;
                    alert(URL);
                        if (URL === "completly link")
                            {
                                document.getElementById("autoiframe").src = "link.html";

                    }}
```

Thanks for help.